# Почему так легко украсть чужие куки firefox?

Tags: безопасность, firefox

Сделал небольшой эксперемент.

Есть

1. Домашний комп с Windows 7
2. Cервер с Windows Server 2012 r2

Установлена там и там последняя версия firefox (с офф сайта).

Что я сделал: скопировал 1 файл (cookies.sqlite) из директории firefox с домашнего компа, в директорию firefox сервера.

В результате на сервере в браузере везде выполнен вход под моими учетками.

Между серваком и домашним компом нет ничего общего.

Как такое могло получиться вообще?

Comment: А почему нет? Что смущает?

Comment: Это никакие не чужие куки, вы скопировали свои собственные куки. Естественно вы как владелец кук можете делать с ними абсолютно что угодно, в том числе утаскивать на другие компьютеры. Что не так?